# Sonarqube validando metodos de outros arquivos JAVA

Tags: java

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma regra no sonarqube, porém me encontro com o seguinte problema:
Se um método de uma classe chama outro metodo , eu quero validar se o metodo chamado existe, porém, eu so tenho acesso aos metodos da minha classe atual, e muitas vezes esse metodo que foi chamado se encontra em outra classe

```
class Connection:
public void metodo_1(){
   metodo_novo();
}
class Arquivos:
public void metodo_novo(){
}
```

no exemplo acima, minha rule daria erro, pois, o metodo esta em outra classe, porém o sonar não consegue enxergar isso, pois ele valida por classes, qual solução eu poderia tomar?